# Not able to change jetpack compose variable within another function

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to change a variable on button click within another function. But i'm getting a syntax error under "currentPage" at this line:

```
"A" -> RegistrationScreen(currentPage)
```

The error says:

***Type mismatch: inferred type is String but MutableState was expected***

Here's the code:

```
@Composable
fun CrossSlideExample() {

    var currentPage by remember { mutableStateOf("A") }

        CrossSlide(targetState = currentPage) { screen ->
            when (screen) {
                "A" -> RegistrationScreen(currentPage)
                "B" -> LoginScreen()
            }
        }

}

@Composable
fun RegistrationScreen(currentPage:MutableState<String>){
    Button(onClick = {
        currentPage.value = "B"
    }) {
        Text(text = "GO TO LOGIN")
    }
}

@Composable
fun LoginScreen(){
    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
        Text(text = "GO BACK TO REGISTRATION")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the  `var currentPage by remember { mutableStateOf("A") }` statement.

Here you are using `by` delegate, which is extracting the value and making the `currentPage` as `String` instead of `MutableState<String>`.

By updating your code to

```
    val currentPage = remember { mutableStateOf("A") }

        CrossSlide(targetState = currentPage.value) { screen ->
            when (screen) {
                "A" -> RegistrationScreen(currentPage)
                "B" -> LoginScreen()
            }
        }
```

This way by avoiding the `by` delegate, you can capture the `MutableState` object directly.

Ref: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `by` [property delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html), the type of `currentPage` is not `MutableState<String>` but just `String`. The fact that it's backed by `MutableState` is hidden. You have two options:

1. Remove `by` keyword and use `currentPage` as `MutableState`:

```
val currentPage = remember { mutableStateOf("A") }
CrossSlide(targetState = currentPage.value) { screen ->
    when (screen) {
        "A" -> RegistrationScreen(currentPage)
        "B" -> LoginScreen()
    }
}
```

2. Keep `by` delegate and add callback to `RegistrationScreen` - this is preferred since having `State` as a function parameter is not recommended.

```
@Composable
fun CrossSlideExample() {
    var currentPage by remember { mutableStateOf("A") }

    CrossSlide(targetState = currentPage) { screen ->
        when (screen) {
            "A" -> {
                RegistrationScreen(
                    currentPage = currentPage,
                    onCurrentPageChange = { currentPage = it },
                )
            }
            "B" -> LoginScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RegistrationScreen(
    currentPage: String, // you don't use the value itself here, so not needed
    onCurrentPageChange: (String) -> Unit,
){
    Button(onClick = {
        onCurrentPageChange("B")
    }) {
        Text(text = "GO TO LOGIN")
    }
}
```